# Using the arrow key in a Jupyter keyboard shortcut

Tags: jupyter-notebook, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like to add `Cmd-↑` as a shortcut for "Move cell up" in Jupyter, but the instructions offer no guidance on how to do so.

Apparently it can be done since, for example, `collapse-heading` and `uncollapse-heading` are bound by default to `←`, `→`, respectively.

Using the exact UTF-8 sequence above doesn't work:

[image: A screenshot of the keyboard shortcuts portion of the Jupyter interface with three parts: (1) the Apple Command key symbol; (2) the word "Undefined"; (3) an "x"]

How can I use arrows in my custom shortcuts?

Answer (score 2):

In late 2020 with Jupyterlab 2.2 it's `ArrowLeft`, `ArrowRight`, `ArrowUp`, and `ArrowDown`

Answer (score 1):

"Ctrl-up" for  Ctrl-up_arrow_key
"Ctrl-down" for Ctrl-down_arrow_key